# Cannot get session data from middleware in node.js

Tags: node.js, session, express, middleware

I have a function that gets the id of the user when she registers

```
            user.save(function(err, id){
                if(err) return next(err);
                req.session.uid=id;                         
            })
```

Then, I wrote this middleware

```
var User = require('../user');//contains the code above
module.exports = function(req,res,next){
    var uid = req.session.uid;
    if(!uid) return next();//if not logged in
    else{//else is logged in
        User.get(uid, function(err, user){
            //get user object and pass it to locals
            if (err) console.log("error from midd > "+err);
            req.user = res.locals.user = user;
            next();
        })
    }
}
```

I define my middleware in the `app.js` like so

```
var user = require('./lib/middleware/user');
app.use(session({resave:'false', saveUninitialized:'false', secret:'secret'}));
app.use(user);  //<-- my middleware
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.set('multimedia', __dirname + '/public/multimedia');
app.use(messages);
app.get('/register', register.form);
app.post('/register', register.submitit);
```

Then I check if there is an id in the locals and show the right menu, by using ejs

```
<%if (locals.user) {%>
  <div id='menu'>
  <a href='/post'>post</a> 
  <a href='/logout'>logout</a>
</div>

<%}else{ %>

<div id='menu'>
  <a href='/login'>login</a> 
  <a href='/register'>sign up</a>
</div>
<%}%>
```

This never works. In every page, even if I am registered, I never see the menu for the registered users (post and logout).

I put many `console.log` all over the code and looks like the middleware never gets the `session.uid`.

`console.log("req.session.uid =  "+req.session.uid);` inside the middleware always gives undefined, even though saving the user works and returns an id that I pass to session `req.session.uid=id;`

How do I fix this? Please advise because I am stuck.

Thanks

Comment: How do you pass `req` to the user code?

Comment: Are you sure `user` in `app.use(user);` is the function of the middleware (looking for a require error here ...)

Comment: @robertklep By this line `module.exports = function(req,res,next){` . I guess `req` there, should do the trick

Comment: @Cyrbil At first I do `var user = require('./lib/middleware/user');` . This contains the whole code of the middleware. Then  I do `app.use(user); `

Comment: When you saved the user, you do not call `next()` which I assume don't let express finish the query and save the altered session properly.

Comment: @Cyrbil Wait. Where do you mean I should call the `next`? In the `user.save`? You lost me

Comment: After req.session.uid = id; you never call next(). Express-session will save the session only if a request end or an explicit call to save()

Answer (score 0):

*Note: I cannot be sure this is your error because you didn't paste the code around `user.save()`. But I'm enoughly confident that is the cause.*

> ***[Session.Save()](https://github.com/expressjs/session#sessionsave)***: This method is automatically called at the end of the HTTP response if the session data has been altered (though this behavior can be altered with various options in the middleware constructor). Because of this, typically this method does not need to be called.

As I can see here:

```
 user.save(function(err, id){
     if(err) return next(err);
     req.session.uid=id;                         
 })
```

You either:

- Fail to save the new user and continue the process with `next(err)` (which end the HTTP response)
- Or succeed and probably get stuck (<= not enough code shown to know what...)

In case of success you should probably call `next()` or `next(null)`.

Because of that, the altered session (ie: `req.session.uid=id;`) is never saved. Thus, resulting in a failure of retrieving the `uid` in the middleware.